# Which Node.js module should I install to be able to use google protocol buffers?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

It seems that there are a few modules available for Node.js from multiple people to work with protocol buffers.  Some are more or less actively maintained. I found https://github.com/chrisdew/protobuf which seems to be working fine. But is there a tried and true (officially certified) path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no official implementations of Protobuf aside from Java, Python and C++. For node.js, you'll probably want to go with chrisdew since it's the one on npm. I personally use my own [fork](https://github.com/seishun/protobuf) because I need to work with int64's.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you forked Chris Dew's implementation?  What is your use case?  Thank you.

Comment: @shargors: I'm developing a [Node.js implementation of Steam](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam). Steam uses protobuf extensively and passes around int64's a lot. chrisdew's module converts int64's into Numbers, losing precision, which is unacceptable for me.

Comment: Do you mean that when proto buf int64 is converted into JavaScript Number then precision is lost?  How could that be?

Comment: And if this is an issue why not to check in a fix into chris dew's code base on github?

Comment: @shargors: JavaScript Numbers are 64-bit floats - enough to store 32-bit ints, but not 64-bit ints. Try typing "76561197976267165" (without quotes) in a JS console and see what you get. I already added a [pull request](https://github.com/chrisdew/protobuf/pull/16) to chrisdew's repo but he doesn't seem to like it and I don't really care.

Answer (score 11):

No doubt... the better,complete and beautifully designed is: [Protobuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js)

Cheers!

Comment: chrisdew's implementarion might not be the best option if you are using windows, in that case you have to make sure all the C++ library are installed. Otherwise you might run into issues like this https://github.com/chrisdew/protobuf/issues/22. So I suggest it is better to go with Protobuf.js.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mention [protocol-buffers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protocol-buffers) nodejs package as an option

Answer (score 2):

Now you already have a JS google official version. You can download it here https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases